# Is it my imagination or did footnote style links stop working in vscode preview mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I always use footnote style links in markdown because it makes the plain text more readable for me. E.g.:

```
This is [Stack Overflow][1].

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com
```

in most Markdown renderers will display as:

> This is [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

I could have sworn I've been doing this all along in vscode. However, recently I notice that it in vscode renders as:

> This is [Stack Overflow][1].

It knows there's something special about the footnote style link because it doesn't render the footnote at all. But the anchor text is not rendered as a link. This seems like a severe regression to me, but I can't find any bugs reported for it.

My specific questions that I am seeking definitive answers on:

- Can anyone confirm that this either did or did not work in the past?
- Has this been intentionally disabled?
- Is this part of the new workspace security settings?

Comment: Note: I'm asking a question here on SO because the vscode github project directs questions to posted here. So don't close this as off topic or too vague. VSCode specifically directs people here, and I have specific questions I'm seeking answers to. If you need clarification, I can clarify.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of VS Code? This is working as expected for me (v1.58.0). Right click an `.md` file and select `Open Preview` displays footnote links correctly.

Comment: in v1.55 it renders as expected

Comment: Markdown, or markdown in vscode, is very finicky in my experience.  You probably have a markdown error somewhere else in the document and it causes other issues down the line.  Try having only that in a markdown file.  Does that work?  It works fine for me in v1.58.

Comment: @vicpermir I've got 1.58.0, and it says there's no updates available.

Comment: @mark It's every `.md` file. Even one that has nothing but a single link. These all pass `markdownlint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to those who commented that it works for them. Knowing that it works for other people really helped narrow down my search for what was wrong.

Turns out the Foam extension was causing this. After disabling it footnote links render properly now.